# How do I determine the bounds of integration when finding these marginal pdfs?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

I am studying for actuarial Exam P using Finan's notes. I have come across a joint probability problem I do not understand how to solve and the answer key only adds to my confusion.

The problem is:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables, with the joint probability density function

$$ f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{3x^2+2y}{24} $$ for $ 0\le x, y\le 2$ and $0$ otherwise. Find $ f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$.

The answer key has the bounds of integration for both integrals to be 0 to 2 and I do not understand why as this does not seem to cover the range of the variables. For example, is $(50, 1)$ not a valid input into $f_{XY}(x,y)$? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In this case we have, $1 \leq x \leq 2$ and $1 \leq y \leq 2$, so it must be a simple integral $f_{X}(x) = \int_{1}^{2} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy$ and $f_{Y}(y) = \int_{1}^{2} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx$ , It is strange that the limits are between 0 and 2

Comment: $f_{XY}(50,1)=0$ as $x=50>2$.  So it is a valid input which gives a zero density, and so need not be in the integral

Comment: @daniel To get $\int \int \frac{3x^2+2y}{24}\, dy \,dx =1$ it seems you need something like $0<x<2$ and $0<y<2$, so the "$1\le x, y\le 2$" may have a typo

Comment: @Henry True, the question makes sense there.

Comment: @Henry you're right I made a typo in my original post, sorry everyone! It should be that X is greater than or equal to 0, not 1 (I have fixed it now). That said, how did you determine that X and Y must be between 0 and 2 for the double integral to equal 1? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @payasa: $\int\limits_0^2 \int\limits_0^2 \frac{3x^2+2y}{24}\, dy \,dx =\int\limits_0^2  \frac{6x^2+4}{24} \,dx =1$

Comment: @Henry I agree that the double integral does equal 1 when x and y are between 0 and 2 but I am wondering how you determined that in the first place? Is there a certain process or was it a guess? Thanks again

Comment: @payasa: from [your original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4849502/revisions), it was likely to be $[0,2]^2$ or $[1,2]^2$ and one of these worked